# How do I mute an audio file after 60 seconds of the audio using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am able to mute sections of the audio file that are within first 60 seconds as shown below, but unsuccessful to mute the sections after first 60 seconds of the audio file.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,10)':volume=0" // This works.

ffmpeg -i audio.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,94,124)':volume=0" // This does not work.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Share the full log of the failed command

Comment: It doesn't return any error as such but when I play the audio file, the audio between 94s and 124s is not muted so I was wondering if I have issue with arguments. Does that look good to you?

Comment: Your command string is incomplete. Run the failed command with -report added and share report

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed a bug in my code and that fixed the issue. 
Follow up question - how can I replace the muted section with some other audio?

  FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("ffmpeg");
  FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("ffprobe");
  FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);
  FFmpegProbeResult in = ffprobe.probe("src/main/resources/Input.wav");
  FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder().setInput(in) 
    .addOutput("src/main/resources/Output.wav").setAudioFilter("volume=enable='between(t,94,124)':volume=0").done();
  executor.createJob(builder).run();

Comment: Added a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693778/how-do-i-add-some-other-audio-to-the-muted-section-of-an-audio-using-ffmpeg

Comment: @GirishMC Can you sent me code mute over 60s. Thanks