# How do I add some other audio to the muted section of an audio using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am muting a section of the audio file as below. How can I add some other audio to the muted section of the audio using ffmpeg?

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("ffmpeg");
FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("ffprobe");
FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);
FFmpegProbeResult in = ffprobe.probe("Input.wav");
FFmpegBuilder builder = new **FFmpegBuilder().setInput(in).addOutput("Output.wav").setAudioFilter("volume=enable='between(t,94,123)':volume=0").done();**
executor.createJob(builder).run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convenient way to do this is to trim the source and concat with the new audio.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -i insert.wav -filter_complex "[0]atrim=0:94[pre];[0]atrim=124,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[post];[1]atrim=0:30[mid];[pre][mid][post]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" out.wav
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gyan. I am using ffmpeg-cli-wrapper, but unfortunately, I am unable to find its matching attribute for "filter_complex" . I will try some other way and then accept the answer.

Comment: For combining multiple inputs, you'll need filter_complex. There is a way to use the concat demuxer, but it can produce glitches at the audio joints.

Comment: I finally found the correct argument but getting the below error. 

Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0]atrim=0:94[pre];[0]atrim=124,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[post];[pre][1][post]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: src/main/resources/ffmpeg returned non-zero exit status. Check stdout.
 at net.bramp.ffmpeg.job.SinglePassFFmpegJob.run(SinglePassFFmpegJob.java:46)
 at com.intuit.redact.RedactPackage.main(RedactPackage.java:39)

Comment: Doesn't look like you added both inputs.

Comment: I have added both inputs. Please see code snippet below.

  FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder().setInput(in1).setInput(in2).setComplexFilter("[0]atrim=0:94[pre];[0]atrim=124,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[post];[pre][1][post]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1").addOutput("src/main/resources/out.wav").done();

where, 
  FFmpegProbeResult in1 = ffprobe.probe("in.wav");
  FFmpegProbeResult in2 = ffprobe.probe("insert.wav");

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. It worked. I was using setInput() method instead of addInput() method for the insert.wav. 

So the new statement looks like this. 

  FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder().setInput(in1).addInput(in2).setComplexFilter("[0]atrim=0:94[pre];[0]atrim=124,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[post];[pre][1][post]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1").addOutput("src/main/resources/out.wav").done();

Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: There is one slight issue. The insert.wav started at 94th second as expected, but continues until 993th second instead of 124th second as specified in your command. Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: So your insert is longer than the muted section? Adjusted command

Comment: That would be great, thanks. I can not use a insert.wav file of fixed length because the pause length varies from audio file to audio.file (in.wav) and the command should be able to replace only the muted section with insert.wav not even a second extra.